# selector as parameter in IOS

Tags: ios, selector

I want to raise a different method for each created button. 
I try to call "FirstImage" method in viewDidLoad but it doesn't work.

I have a problem with the selector in ViewDidLoad. Didn't recognise "FirstImage" which is a void method without parameter.

ViewController.m

```
- (void)createFirstButton:(NSString *)myName: (SEL *)myAction{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn        addTarget:self
                action:@selector(myAction)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setTitle:myName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 916, 120, 68);
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [self createFirstButton:@"First" myAction:[self FirstImage]];
}
```

What I have done (I changed "CreateFirstButton" into "CreateButton") :

ViewControler.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myHeight;
@synthesize myWidth;
@synthesize myX;
@synthesize myY;

- (void)createButton:(NSString *)myName:(SEL)myAction:(NSUInteger)my_x:(NSUInteger)my_y:(NSUInteger)my_width:(NSUInteger)my_height
{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn    addTarget:self
            action:myAction
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setTitle:myName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(my_x, my_y, my_width, my_height);
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

- (void)myXcrementation{
    myX = myX + 150; 
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    myX = 20; myY = 916; myWidth = 120; myHeight = 68;
    [self createButton:@"First":@selector(FirstImage):myX:myY:myWidth:myHeight];
    [self myXcrementation];
    [self createButton:@"Previous":@selector(PreviousImage):myX:myY:myWidth:myHeight];
    [self myXcrementation];
    [self createButton:@"Pause":@selector(PauseImage):myX:myY:myWidth:myHeight];
    [self myXcrementation];
    [self createButton:@"Next":@selector(NextImage):myX:myY:myWidth:myHeight];
    [self myXcrementation];
    [self createButton:@"Last":@selector(LastImage):myX:myY:myWidth:myHeight];
}

- (void)FirstImage{
    current = 0;
    [self SetImage];
}

-(void)SetImage{
    [myImageView setImage: [myArray objectAtIndex:(current)]];
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
}

@property(assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger myHeight;
@property(assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger myWidth;
@property(assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger myX;
@property(assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger myY;

@end
```

I edited this post again and there is no more error.
Special thanks to everybody. It took me time to understand :)

Comment: I wonder-all buttons having same frame?

Comment: And it will also crash with `Unrecognized selector`, since the message you're implementing is called `createFirstButton::` and not `createFirstButton:myAction:`. Furthermore, you don't need `SEL *` (similarly to `id`): `SEL` is sufficient. In addition, `@selector(myAction)` doesn't do what you think it does, use simply `myAction` in its place.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use use `@selector` as follows

```
[self createFirstButton:@"First" myAction:@selector(FirstImage)];
```

Then your signature is wrong, since `SEL` shouldn't be a pointer.

Change

```
- (void)createFirstButton:(NSString *)myName: (SEL *)myAction{
```

to

```
- (void)createFirstButton:(NSString *)myName: (SEL)myAction{
```

Finally `myAction` has type `SEL` so you can pass it directly to the `UIButton` method, as follows

```
[btn addTarget:self
     action:myAction
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Also, I'd like to add that using capitalized names for methods it's a very bad practice.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to iOS I did too many errors. I try to correct it.

Comment: don't be sorry, It's perfectly ok to make mistakes when approaching a new language/framework ;) Fix everything I pointed out and you should be ok.

Comment: If the FirstImage method has arguments this will not work. For example we may want to identify the button from where the request came like the sender id of that method. Any ideas how to change it to accommodate methods with arguments?

Comment: In the method name, why do you have the colon butting up against the name of the variable?  This is a complex method name and the colon needs to be next to the argument for it.  There should be a space between myName and the colon and no space between the colon and (SEL *)myAction.  This matters, because the colon has nothing to do with the data to the left of it and everything to do with the data to the right of it.

Comment: @AlexZavatone, just copy-pasted from the OP's question and I didn't bother changing it since it wasn't the point here. Feel free to edit

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [self createFirstButton:@"First" myAction:@selector(FirstImage)];
}
```

or

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [self createFirstButton:@"First" myAction:NSSelectorFromString(@"FirstImage")];
}
```

`@selector(myAction)` should be replaced with `myAction`, and `(SEL *)` should be replaced with `SEL`.

In your code, before `-createFirstButton:myAction:` is called, its second parameter `[self FirstImage]` would be evaluated(called) first. @selector() takes a name and returns a SEL.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I still got this message : No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'createFirstButton:myAction:'

Comment: @icewall0, you should declare `- (void)createFirstButton:(NSString *)myName myAction:(SEL)myAction;` between `@interface ViewController` and `@end` in its header file if it should be exposed as a public method or between `@interface ViewController()` and `@end` before `@implementation` as a private method.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[self createFirstButton:@"First" withAction:NSSelectorFromString(@"FirstImage")];
```

And change the method name as :

```
- (void)createFirstButton:(NSString *)myName: withAction: (SEL) myAction{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn        addTarget:self
                action:myAction
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setTitle:myName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 916, 120, 68);
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

Also,

I wonder-all buttons having same frame, if possible pass `frame` this method.

Comment: I planned to use variable for frame

Comment: @icewall0 : should I mention how you can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the method literal as in the following

```
- (void)createFirstButton: (NSString *)myName withAction: (SEL)myAction
```

For both declaration and definition.

And also why have you declared the same method as a public as well as private?

Comment: Building succeeded but I still get crashed when I press on my FirstButton. I worked too much on this piece of code I'm tired sorry

Comment: What the message are you getting at log after pressing the button while it crashed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to pass string as method name to selector, then use NSSelectorFromString. String should end with ':' Example-

```
    NSString *myName=@"aMethod:"; 
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:NSSelectorFromString(myName)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```