# How can I pas another object's function as a selector in IOS?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I've read [selector as parameter in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083763/selector-as-parameter-in-ios) post. However, I want to extend the question.

In my case, I'm creating an Objective-C (not Swift) Master/Detail application, and want to create DetailController object of type UIViewController with the following init function

In DetailViewController.h

```
@interfact DetailViewController : UIViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName withSaveSelector:(SEL)saveSelector
@end
```

... and in DetailViewController.m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName withSaveSelector:(SEL)saveSelector
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
  if (self) {
        UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                 target:self
                                 action:saveSelector];
        [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:done animated:YES];
  }
  return self;
}
```

NOW, I want to just keep re-using above code to create different DetailViewControllers, and want to pass a saveSelector function that will get called when the user presses the "Done" button.

Now I have another view controller

```
@interface AnotherViewController : UIViewController
- (void)saveSelector:(id)sender;
@end
```

...and then in yet another object (i.e., **NOT in AnotherViewController.m code**), I use the above view controller, like so...

```
AnotherViewController *avc = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];
DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" withSaveSelector:@selector(???)];
```

What should I put in the ??? so I can pass AnotherViewController::saveSelector() function to DetailViewController?

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method as:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName withSaveSelector:(SEL)saveSelector forTarget:(id)target
```

And call it like this:

```
DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" withSaveSelector:@selector(saveSelector:) forTarget:avc];
```

In `DetailViewController.m`

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName withSaveSelector:(SEL)saveSelector  forTarget:(id)target
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
  if (self) {
        UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                 target:target
                                 action:saveSelector];
        [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:done animated:YES];
  }
  return self;
}
```